# Calling method / function from another stateful class to another stateful class not working correctly using Keys

Tags: android, flutter, dart, oop, flutter-layout

So I'm trying to use a method from class BlackJacScreen in another class called BJSettings, for the implementation I tried using keys to access it.

the method I'm trying to run is

```
void setBal(int tempVal) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setInt("temp", tempVal);
setState(() {
  temp = tempVal;
});
```

}

so in my BJSettings page I created a globalkey variable

```
 GlobalKey<BlackJacScreenState> _key = GlobalKey<BlackJacScreenState>();
```

and a button with an onpressed

```
    ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _key.currentState?.setBal(60);
                })
```

how will i be able to run the _key.currentState?.setBal(60); method ?
I have also even tried to run simpler method, such as a simple print method but I couldnt be able to make the function run at all, am i missing something??
I understand that this could be done using state management, but I'm just trying to learn how keys work,,,
state management aside, for example if my function or method that I want to use is

`void hello (){ print("Hello world"); }`

at BlackJacScreen, how can i access this method using KEYS in another stateful class?

Comment: Haven't you tried to declare the function static and call it from where ever you want? And if you need to change the state of a widget from somewhere else then you need to use some state management technique.

Comment: thats not what im looking for or what im asking, I'm asking how to access the method / function using keys...

Comment: Flutter commonly uses keys when it needs to uniquely identify specific widgets within a collection. The purpose you are trying to acheive using keys in flutter isn't meant it to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ChangeNotifier for what you're trying to accomplish. Checkout the flutter docs about state management [Flutter's simple state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: alright state management aside, for example if my function or method that I want to use is void hello (){print("Hello world");}   at BlackJacScreen, how can i access this method using KEYS in another stateful class?

Comment: Ah ok. If that's the case, you gotta pass the global key to the widget where you call the function. ElevatedButton(key:_key,
                onPressed: () {
                  _key.currentState?.setBal(60);
                })